# Can I detect iOS' "darken colors" setting?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiappearance

I noticed that my app doesn't look good when the "darken colors" iOS system setting is enabled. Some navigation buttons are white, some are darkened to gray.

Is there any way to detect if this setting is enabled?

Comment: iOS 7.1 gives the users the ability to darken colors/increase contrast. Are you referring to that? I doubt, if we have control over it.

Comment: the _darken colours_ is part of presenting a better view for disabled people, who may have colour-blind, cataract or any other issues with their eyes. you must not interfere with it, even if the colours look strange for your healthy eyes.

Comment: @holex, Your comment is not helpful. I need to find out the setting to make sure that all navigation elements are darkened not just a few of them.

Comment: @raurora, yes, I'm referring to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's quite easy to detect. Suppose the navigationBar is configured with a white `tintColor`. Just reading `navigationBar.tintColor` returns the adjusted color, in this case 80% white. We can use this color to set the `navigationBar.titleTextAttributes`.

For all tintable elements such as UIBarButtonItems, make sure to use template images only:

```
-[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]
```