# Can I detect if iPhone has blur enabled?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitoolbar, blur

Starting with the iPhone 4S `UIToolbar` blurs the background. However the user can manually disable blurring in the Settings under General > Accessibility > Increase Contrast > Reduce Transparency.

Can I programmatically find out if the iPhone actually does use blurring?

The reason is I'd like to adjust the background and barTintColor in case of blurring being disabled or unavailable.

Related, for the "Darken Colors" setting I found a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921649/235297) to detect it. I'm looking for something similar for the blurring as I'm not aware of a public API for this.

Comment: let me quote the point from me here again: the _accessibility option_ is part of presenting a better view for **disabled people**, who may have colour-blind, cataract or any other issues with their eyes. you must not interfere with it, even if the colours look strange for your healthy eyes. you **do not** make any adjustment of colours in that scenario. focus on your regular design only and let the Apple do with colours what they think as the best colour-adjustment for those people.

Comment: Holex, we all apreciate you comments, but remember: we are here first to learn things about programming and "how to do things". How can you say that Ortwin doesn't have a "disabled" (sorry but I don't know if it's the correct term in english) colleague that can help him to build a more efficient way to present the views/colors to its users? You don't have enough informations to judge. Moreover, it seems that Apple doesn't think like you (fortunately), because they added an API just in iOS 8.0. Regards

Comment: @holex, I repeat it again: I know what I'm doing and why I'm doing it. If you disagree, feel free to post a question to http://ux.stackexchange.com. Let's focus on answering the question, not debating it.

Comment: @LombaX, the Apple has correct policy how they like to deal with their own disabled customers.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz, I'm not caring about you, I'm caring about people who you'd like to care at all with messing up the standard Accessibility-policy. you are not a doctor to decide which colour/contrast is _better_ for disabled people. it is a guess only because I have never ask Apple about it, but we (including you) can be sure the Apple has more professional team to decide and make algorithm how the colours should be re-factored then individual developers even if _they think they know what they are doing_. your confidence about it is aggressive and high-minded behaviour only...... good luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to check user's `Reduce Transparency` setting under iOS 8 with: [`UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/).

As for the devices running iOS 7, blur isn't supported on iPhone 4, iPad 2 and 3 (I'm not 100% sure about iPad 2).

Comment: Thanks, I actually overlooked that function (and apparently, it's not yet in the documentation, only in the API diff). That's at least a solution for iOS 8. I leave the question open though in the hope someone comes up with a solution for iOS 7.

Comment: Also, I just verified that blur is not supported on iPad 2.