# UINavigationBar & UITabbar tintColor not working in iPhone6Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm developing iOS app using Swift2 & Xcode7. I want to change UINavigationBar & UITabbar tintColor, so I write the below code in AppDelegate.swift.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.appThemeColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)
]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12.0)
    ], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
    NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12.0)
    ], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.appThemeColor()
```

But tabbar selected icon's color and navigation bar icon's color are not white but lightgray-ish in only iPhone6plus(iOS8.1). In iPhone6S(iOS9.0) and iPhone5(iOS8.4), all are work well. Do you know reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `Settings` > `General` > `Accessibilty` > `Increase Contrast` and turn off `Darken Colors`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921649/3950397).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for.